# Sorting by meta_key different to search criteria?

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, meta-query

I've created an admin only page simply to view more information about subscribers to my website. The subscriptions are stored as Custom Post Types.

All I want to do is make a condition that looks up a list of cancelled subscribers and orders them by the expiry of the subscription. The subscription expiry is stored as yyyymmdd as a meta tag on the post.

There are a few pages about this, but I cannot get any solution to work in my instance and it's probably because I'm doing something stupid.

The two I have tried are:

```
     $args=array(
            'post_type' => 'subscription',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'meta_key' => 'expiry',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
            'meta_query' => array(
                                  array(
                                        'key' => 'paypal_recur_profile_status',
                                        'value' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'cancelled',true),
                                        'compare' => '='
                                        )

                                  ),
            );
```

and

```
 $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'subscription',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => array('paypal_recur_profile_status', 'expiry'),
        'meta_value' => 'Cancelled',
        'orderby' => 'expiry'
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'caller_get_posts'=> 1,
        );
```

The first returns nothing, the second seems to do ok but has some anomalies in it so assume it ends up ordering it by post number and the other correct order results are coincidental.

Can anybody spot the un-deliberate mistake in here or is this simply the wrong way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: What are the possible values of `paypal_recur_profile_status`? Is `paypal_recur_profile_status` the custom field indicating whether a subscription has been cancelled?

Comment: Yes @engelen the meta_key is `paypal_recur_profile_status` and it should be `Cancelled` in this case to start the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value for the `value` key in the meta query is probably the cause of the problem.

```
 'value' => get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'cancelled', true )
```

The `get_post_meta` call actually retrieves the value of the meta key "cancelled" for the current post. So, in your current `WP_Query`, you're retrieving all posts with a `paypal_recur_profile_status` equal to the value of the custom field "cancelled" of the current post.

If you want to get posts that have a profile status of `Cancelled`, you should check `value` to be "Cancelled":

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'subscription',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_key' => 'expiry',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'=> 1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'paypal_recur_profile_status',
            'value' => 'Cancelled'
        )
    )
);
```

Furthermore, `caller_get_posts` was replaced by `ignore_sticky_posts` in WordPress 3.1 (so I've replaced that), and you can omit the `compare` key in the `meta_query`, as that's `=` by default.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely perfect @engelen thank you. Have accepted and +1 for helping me out - it's the problem with teaching yourself PHP - sometimes the basic mistakes get missed.